# Convert points with x,y coords and value from to a raster image

Tags: qgis, point, dem, rasterization

I have a CSV file with xcoord,ycoord and pixel value from DEM. After I import it in QGIS, I take this table.
[image]

[image]

I want to make a raster from this point layer. I tried rasterized (vector to raster), I put exactly the dimensions I want (1028x1310,30x30, taken from masked DEM) but raster cannot be created. I also tried with grid but no result. What is my mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an interpolation tool to convert your points to a surface.  [Here is a tutorial on interpolation](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/interpolating_point_data.html) that may help you get started.  [Here is a link to the interpolation tools](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html) available in QGIS.

Comment: That worked, thanks you very much .